# How can i get only the date and time in selenium IDE

Tags: date, selenium

I'm using selenium IDE and i would like to capture only the date and time from a field that was updated

Example:

Updated by James in 07/05/2015 - 09:50

I need to get only this date and the time from the record updated

Is there a way to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do it with storeEval(). You can use JavaScript to manipulate stored variables. Lets assume that you stored that whole text in variable *updated*

```
${updated} == "Updated by James in 07/05/2015 - 09:50"
```

Now we just need to get that variable and get part of its text:

```
Command: storeEval()
Target:  storedVars['updated'].split(' ')[4]
Value:   date
```

Basically we get *updated* and we split it into array using space as separator, and then we get 4th element of array, which contains date and store in it new variable *date*.

Now:

```
${date} == "07/05/2015"
```

The same you can do with time.